# Use of bootstrap grid system for layouts, content and components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I've been using twitter bootstrap as well as zurb foundation in a few web projects and while their grid systems are perfect for organizing the general layout of the page (top menu, sidebars, and so on) as well as actual content (putting three paragraphs of text side by side for example) something that I never found entirely clear is if you're meant to use them for smaller components of a page: for example, should I use grids and nested grids every time I need two elements to be side by side?

The provided [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) are two toyish to be really helpful in understanding that.

**Edit:** I realize from the first comments that I did not make myself clear so I'll clarify with a specific example: a screenshot of a github page.

[image]

The two areas marked with an orange rectangle are obviously good candidates for the grid system. But if we dive a little more into the page what about these ones:

[image]

The left title could be part of a 6 column, the buttons on the left could be part of a 6 column as well, and each of the button could be part of a nested 4-column sub grid.

This could be done this way, but should it?

Comment: What is the alternative to using grid elements?

Comment: Using responsive tables maybe a solution that you can also integrate with a grid to specify column widths.Check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive. You can also see a working example of a project I'm working on.  http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/cover.html